# Saying for "people who are in a similar situation and understand each other"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

I'm pretty sure there's a saying for "people who are in a similar situation and understand each other". Unfortunately, I can't even come up with it in my native language (Spanish).

Example:

> A: You broke up with your boyfriend.
>
> B: What? How do you know?
>
> A: Because I broke up with my partner too. [The saying goes here].

Answer (score 2):

The closest that I can think of is not a saying but an idiomatic expression [I know what it's like...](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-what-it-is-like-to)

> I know what it's like to be out of work... I was on the dole for three years
>
> I know what it's like when you break up... John and I split up three months ago and I'm still not over it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but:

- **[To be on the same wavelength](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+the+same+wavelength)** - People who think in a similar way and understand each other well.
- **Empathy** - the power of understanding and imaginatively entering into another person's feelings. - If we are talking about feeling the same way!
- **To be in the same boat** - to be in the same unpleasant situation as other people.

Comment: I think the third answer is a pretty good match for what the OP is asking.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it's not!

Answer (score 0):

Being empathetic means one understands what another may be feeling in a situation.